# PyQGIS (3.2) and H5PY DLL problem

Tags: pyqgis, hdf5

I am working in a project in which I need to use PyQGIS and H5PY. The problem comes  when I load qgis library and h5py, for example:

```
import qgis
import h5py
```

I get this error:

from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
  File "h5py\h5r.pxd", line 21, in init h5py._conv
  File "h5py_objects.pxd", line 12, in init h5py.h5r
  File "h5py_objects.pyx", line 1, in init h5py._objects
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado.

I am using QGIS 3.2 and H5py 2.8.0 with Python36 interpreter contained in QGIS installation folder. H5py was installed through the command:

```
python -m pip install h5py
```

I tried other versions of H5py (2.6.0, 2.7.1) but I had the same problem.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this dll interaction problem?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046796/importerror-dll-load-failedimport-h5py

Comment: As Marc Pfister's link shows, there is an osgeo4w package for that library and it's recommended to install those instead of pip packages. It's name for python3 is python3-h5py, Version: 2.8.0-1 (32 bit, 64bit may differ)

Comment: I tried with OSGEO4w package but a new problem comes up. When I install the version 2.7.0-1 it throws a message saying that the version of the HDF5 library does not match with the version of the library (QGIS). Version 2.8.0-1 comes with Python37 which has some strange behaviour with Qt module (I think it does not find the correct qt.conf file) that I have to solve. Thanks!

Comment: I have checked with QGIS 3.4 and even loading h5py module from python console inside QGIS 3.4 program the dll problem still persist...

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you don't have HDF5 built on your machine. All that h5py does is it creates a more pythonic API for accessing the compiled libraries on your machine. If you don't have the base libraries (DLLs), it will fail.

Start by uninstalling h5py with `python -m pip uninstall h5py` and then proceed through the installation/configuration instructions for HDF5 (https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/). After that, reinstall h5py. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had python package `gdal` installed using OSGeo4W environment. And then I installed `h5py` using PyCharm (maybe it is important). And realized, that when importing gdal (osgeo, ogr, ...) before importing h5py library, I get the same error as you. But when I import h5py first, no error appears. Don't know why, but maybe it helps someone.

Well I have tried it also with `qgis` library and it's the same. So I would try first import h5py library and then qgis:

```
import h5py
import qgis
```